# fat-free framework sessions variable inaccessible from another method

Tags: php, session, fat-free-framework

I have a method login in my controller where i initialise the session like this.

```
$sess=new \DB\SQL\Session($db);
$id=session_id();
$data=...;
if(!$sess->read($id))
   $sess->write($id,json_encode($data));
......
```

It works fine, but the problem is that the `$sess` variable is not accessible outside this method, i would like to access it somewhere else during logout to destroy the session and close like this.

```
$sess= \DB\SQL\Session::instance();
$sess->destroy();
$sess->close();
```

But i get an error 
`Call to undefined method DB\SQL\Session::instance()`
Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize the SQL Session class, itÄll set itself as default php session handler. Thus you only need to clear the global session just as usual with `$f3->clear('SESSION');`. That's all.

Comment: thanks for the help, the error is gone but now the data in the session table is not being deleted, how can i delete that row written during logon? I have updated my question on how i initialise the session after credentials have been verified.

Comment: the php garbage collector will delete the table data automatically when it's necessary... no need to care about that.